Changing color of multiple cells in a specific row
I copy a row from one sheet to another.
Then I want to change the color of multiple cells based on cell values. The last cell is the only cell that changes color.
For k = 1 To column_count
    If ws1.Cells(i, k).value <> ws2.Cells(j, k).value Or (Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, k).value) And IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(j, k).value)) Or (IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, k).value) And Not IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(j, k).value)) Then

        ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.Rows(lastRow3)
                    
        'change the cell color to red 
        ws3.Rows(lastRow3).Cells(1, k).Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If 

Next k


ws3.Rows(lastRow3).Cells(1, k) is one cell. Which cells are you trying to change the color of?

If you want the cells to be different colours depending on their values, you could use conditional formatting

color of multiple cells. depending on which cell suffices the condition. I am using k as my column index. however it is not changing to red

Do the cells being copied have any Conditional Formatting applied?  FYI you're copying the whole row potentially multiple times....  Each time it get copied it overwrites any previous color set by your code.

@TimWilliams as long as the cell value passes the condition, it should be color red

@TimWilliams Thank you for pointing that out. It is caused by the overwrite. Thanks again!

You're copying the whole row potentially multiple times, so each time it's copied you will overwrite any previous red fill, and only the last-filled cell will remain red.
You only need to copy the row one time:
Dim vi, vj, copied As Boolean

For k = 1 To column_count
    vi = ws1.Cells(i, k).Value
    v2 = ws2.Cells(j, k).Value
    copied = False         'reset flag
    If vi <> vj Or (Not IsEmpty(vi) And IsEmpty(vj)) Or _
         (IsEmpty(vi) And Not IsEmpty(vj)) Then
        If Not copied Then 'row has been copied?
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.Rows(lastRow3)
            copied = True  'flag as copied
        End If
        'change the cell color to red
        ws3.Rows(lastRow3).Cells(1, k).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next k

